# Is there a way to define significance to say something has "fatter" tails?

Tags: statistical-significance, kurtosis

I have two distributions of data. The means are about the same, but one data set has longer, fatter tails. Is there a way I can say one distribution has significantly "fatter" or "longer" tails than the other? The population size for both distributions are equal. Ideally, Id like to implement the solution in R.

Comment: Do you mean something like a test of kurtosis equality like we have tests of mean equality?

Comment: @Dave, yep, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: There's multiple possible ways to measure heaviness of tail. Some guidance about what you want to achieve may help narrow it down a bit. Can you say more about what this conclusion would be used to do?

Comment: @Glen_b Im trying to say that one of the distributions has more outliers than the other distribution, and I want to say this doesn't happen by chance.

Comment: The notion of an outlier doesn't have anything to do with whether a distribution has heavy or light tails. An outlier tends to be an "inconvenient" data point that is not well explained by the preferred model/explanation for the data.

Comment: I agree with dipetkov (whats an outlier depends on the model) but let's say we were to try to proceed ... all you have done is shifted the question from how to define tail heaviness to that of precisely defining an outlier. Replacing one imprecise term with another gets nowhere. This is why I raised the question of your *purpose*. If it really is about outliers, why do more outliers matter?

Comment: A *post hoc* test based on an observation made in the data is invalid.  (It's an example of HARKing).  Thus, we should look askance at answers that propose hypothesis tests of any sort. But you legitimately ask for a way to "say," rather than formally test.  One of the most specific ways to *see* and *quantify* a difference in distributions is a QQ plot, which is native in `R` (and most statistical computing platforms).

Comment: @dipetkov Please forgive my misuse of language. The outlier comment was incorrect. The observation I am seeing is one distribution of data has fatter tails, and by comparison to the control distribution, these fatter tails appear to be "outliers". Clearly I am lacking the correct terminology to explain this. The comments and suggested solutions should get me closer. I need to do some reading and learning. Thank you for your help and insight.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I am using the wrong terminology. I agree a QQ plot is likely what I want to show the differences in the distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **kurtosis** of a distribution is a measure of how much mass there is in its tails. From the mathematical definition below, you can tell that kurtosis cannot be negative; the kurtosis of the normal distribution is 3. $$Kurtosis=\frac{E[(Y-\mu_Y)^4]}{\sigma^4_Y}$$ The plot below shows that the t distribution with d.f.=5 (red) has fatter tails than the normal distribution (black).

[image]

```r
library(moments)
set.seed(10)

nobs = 1000000
norm <- rnorm(nobs)
tdist <- rt(nobs, df=5)
plot(density(norm), xlim=c(-4, 4), ylim = 
c(0, 0.45), col="black", lwd=2, main="", 
ann=F)
par(new=T)
plot(density(tdist), xlim=c(-4, 4), 
     ylim = c(0, 0.45), col="red", lwd=2, 
     main="", ann=F)
text(-3, 0.4, paste0("kurtosis=", 
     round(moments::kurtosis(norm), 2)))
text(3, 0.4, paste0("kurtosis=", 
     round(moments::kurtosis(tdist), 2)), 
     col="red")
```

Comment: The moments library is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider the following fictitious
datasets sampled from exponential and [gamma
distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) in R. All have 1000 observations and
all three populations have mean $15,$ but gamma distributions with larger shape parameters have
thinner right tails. Note: $\mathsf{Exp}(1/15) \equiv \mathsf{Gamma}(1, 1/15).$

```r
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rexp(1000, 1/15)
x2 = rgamma(1000, 3, 1/5)
x3 = rgamma(1000, 5, 1/3)

boxplot(x1, x2, x3, horizontal=T, 
               col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

Boxplots of the three samples (`x1` at bottom).

[image]

The plot below shows the histogram of each sample along with its population distribution, with a
vertical line at the 95th percentile of the distribution. (Smaller 95th percentiles are associated with thinner right tails.)

[image]

R code for figure:

```r
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hist(x1, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.07), xlim=c(0,120), 
     col="skyblue2")
curve(dexp(x, 1/15), add=T, col="brown", lwd=3)
abline(v = qexp(.95, 1/15))
hist(x2, prob=T, xlim=c(0,120), col="skyblue2")
curve(dgamma(x, 3, 1/5), add=T, col="darkgreen", 
      lwd=3)
abline(v = qgamma(.95, 3, 1/5))
hist(x3, prob=T, xlim=c(0,120), col="skyblue2")
curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1/3), add=T, col="purple", 
     lwd=3)
abline(v = qgamma(.95, 5, 1/3))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

In the right tails the purple density function lies below the green one, which in turn lies below the brown one.

Comment: Histograms work poorly for comparing tails.  At a minimum, consider histograms of strongly transformed data (such as logs for positive data).  Better, consider alternative visualizations.

Comment: This was educational. Plotting the 95th percentile helps, but I the metric I was looking for is kurtosis.

Comment: Kurtosis isn't _exactly_ the same thing as 'fat tail'.